# Qual método usar para o código não ficar grande

Tags: javascript, html

Bom dia!!!

Estou criando um código que crie todas a possibilidades com valores inteiros preenchidos nos campos, ou que estão *vazios*, fui fazer teste para cada campo que eu acrescento no meu *html*, e cada campo que eu coloco, dobrava o numero de condições para verificar se os campos estão vazios ou preenchidos. Até o momento estou usando *3* campos para gerar as possibilidades.
Gostaria de criar algum método que não fique com o código muito grande.

```js
function gerar() {
  n1 = document.getElementById("n1").value;
  n2 = document.getElementById("n2").value;
  n3 = document.getElementById("n3").value;
  resultado = "";
  //Gera combinações de números somente com números que falta para completar:

  if (n1 == "" && n2 == "" && n3 == "") {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
          resultado += i + "-" + j + "-" + k + "<br>";
        }
      }
    }
  } else if (n1 == "" && n2 == "" && n3 != "") {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        resultado += i + "-" + j + "-" + n3 + "<br>";
      }
    }
  } else if (n1 == "" && n2 != "" && n3 == "") {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        resultado += i + "-" + n2 + "-" + j + "<br>";
      }
    }
  } else if (n1 == "" && n2 != "" && n3 != "") {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      resultado += i + "-" + n2 + "-" + n3 + "<br>";
    }
  } else if (n1 != "" && n2 == "" && n3 == "") {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
        resultado += n1 + "-" + i + "-" + j + "<br>";
      }
    }
  } else if (n1 != "" && n2 == "" && n3 != "") {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      resultado += n1 + "-" + i + "-" + n3 + "<br>";
    }
  } else if (n1 != "" && n2 != "" && n3 == "") {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      resultado += n1 + "-" + n2 + "-" + i + "<br>";
    }
  } else {
    resultado += n1 + "-" + n2 + "-" + n3 + "<br>";
  }
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = resultado;
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gerador de possibilidades números</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="n1" value=""> -
  <input type="number" id="n2" value=""> -
  <input type="number" id="n3" value="">
  <button onclick="gerar()">Gerar</button>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Não percebi bem o que pretendes... por exemplo se inserires `1-3-5` queres mostrar 1 resultado ou vários? podes dar exemplos?

Comment: mostrar só 1, se deixar algum campo a vazio, ele vai gerar as possibilidades de combinações. faça um teste com 1, 2 ou todos os campos vazio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não entendi o propósito, mas dá para reproduzir com algumas verificações. No caso, como uma string vazia convertida em inteiro resulta em `NaN`, verifiquei se o retorna não era NaN para controlar o loop.

```js
function gerar() {
  n1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n1").value);
  n2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n2").value);
  n3 = parseInt(document.getElementById("n3").value);
  resultado = "";
  
  for (i = n1 || 0, ix = isNaN(n1) ? 10 : i+1; i < ix; i++) {
    for (j = n2 || 0, jx = isNaN(n2) ? 10 : j+1; j < jx; j++) {
      for (k = n3 || 0, kx = isNaN(n3) ? 10 : k+1; k < kx; k++) {
         resultado += i + "-" + j + "-" + k + "<br>";
      } 
    } 
  }
  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = resultado;
}
```

```css
input {
  width: 25px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Gerador de possibilidades números</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
  <input type="number" id="n1" value=""> -
  <input type="number" id="n2" value=""> -
  <input type="number" id="n3" value="">
  <button onclick="gerar()">Gerar</button>
  <div id="resultado"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: vlw era isso que eu queria!!!